# Issue retrieving ConnectivityManager in a device with multi sim

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, connectivity

I am having an issue getting ConnectivityManager:

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

I am using the application context, and I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: missing IConnectivityManager
at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:52)
at android.net.ConnectivityManager.<init>(ConnectivityManager.java:1045)
at android.net.MultiSimConnectivityManager.<init>(MultiSimConnectivityManager.java:86)
at android.app.ContextImpl$12.createService(ContextImpl.java:463)
at android.app.ContextImpl$ServiceFetcher.getService(ContextImpl.java:346)
at android.app.ContextImpl.getSystemService(ContextImpl.java:2036)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemService(ContextWrapper.java:551)
```

Have you seen this issue? Is there any way to solve it?

Thanks,
Diego.

Comment: May be this context is null please check this

Comment: also check the manifest permission

Comment: I am calling context.getApplicationContext(), it must not be null.     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> is there.

Comment: Can you please post the full code.@Diego Gomez Olvera

Answer (score 0):

Connectivity Service is null.

```
public ConnectivityManager(Context context, IConnectivityManager service) {
    mContext = checkNotNull(context, "missing context");
    mService = checkNotNull(service, "missing IConnectivityManager");
    sInstance = this;
}
```

Please check if Connectivity Service is running on your device.

```
adb shell service list | grep connectivity
13      connectivity_metrics_logger: [android.net.IConnectivityMetricsLogger]
64      connectivity: [android.net.IConnectivityManager]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are facing such issue of IconnectivityManager, then you might be getting the context null, at some point or in some cases.,
Since you might be doing this in a service where context might be null thus, you can do one thing such as:

```
 if (context != null) {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

something like this>>